# Android O & Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to look into some weird notification things going on when I upgrade a device to Android O.  So I updated my build.gradle to compile 26, use build tools 26.0.0 and targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 26.

As soon as I do that and try to build, I get the following error because I have Gradle 3.3

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformJackWithJackForArmDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack configuration exception.
  Property 'jack.library.import' (in Options): element #7: The version of the library file 'D:\MyApp\mobile\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\arm\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-44505c402b1b3aca59892e402ff918e0e2aeaf13.jar' is not supported anymore. Library version: 3.3 - Current version: 3.5 - Minimum compatible version: 3.5
```

So it wants me to update to 3.5, as soon as I do that, I get the following error saying I need to revert back to 3.3

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':mobile'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.android.build.gradle.model.AndroidComponentModelPlugin']
   > Gradle version 3.3 is required. Current version is 3.5. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\MyApp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

I assume that my 3.3 error is because I'm using experimental Gradle 0.9.2. But as soon as I use anything other then this, I can't compile the application due to a list of other errors.  My favorite being "Null dimension for Arm.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.2'
}
```

my build.gradle versions
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        buildToolsVersion = '26.0.0'

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 26
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        //Added for test
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "happyApp")
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
```

NOTE: I am using the experimental version of Gradle because my application uses NDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`, and work on issues that arise with the current stable version.

You're using an experimental version of a 3 year old plugin, so I'd be very surprised if it continues to work with the latest version of Android.

Comment: Understood the plugin is old, but finding documentation is like finding launch codes for post cold war missles

Comment: In thinking about this more, I don't think that I can switch to 2.3.3, I appear to have not mentioned that I am using NDK, and to the best of my knowledge I can not use 2.3.3 with NDK.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK 8.0 (API 26+),  Gradle plugin version 3.0.0-beta4 or higher and Android plugin version 4.1 is required. I guess you are missing to update the Android plugin version.

Refer: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html for details.

Comment: @GREnvoy Not sure about NDK man !! But at least its working for me for SDKs.

Comment: I had mentioned that I was using the NDK, compiling with that is different and I am sure the reason for my errors.

Comment: Yes possibly. One suggestion, Can you cross check if your Android Plugin version is 4.1+ as its required in order to  work with Gradle 3.3+.